# Implementation of GroupBy<TKey, TElement> in .NET

Tags: c#, linq

I've implemented the **`GroupBy`** extension method for **`IEnumerable<T>`** type as an excersise to deep a little more into **LINQ**.

What do you think about the source code?

**Code:**

```
static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey,TElement>> GroupBy<TKey,TElement>(this IEnumerable<TElement> source, Func<TElement,TKey> keySelector)
{
    //Grouping elements in the dictionary according to the criteria
    var dict = new Dictionary<TKey, List<TElement>>();

    //Filling the dictionary. It will contain: [Key -> List<Values>]
    foreach (var x in source)
    {
        var key = keySelector(x);
        if (dict.Keys.Contains(key))
        {
            dict[key].Add(x);
        }
        else
        {
            dict.Add(key, new List<TElement> { x });
        }
    }

    //For each group...
    foreach (var x in dict)
    {
        yield return new Grouping<TKey, TElement>(x.Key, x.Value);
    }
}

class Grouping<TKey, TElement> : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
{
    private TKey _key;
    private IEnumerable<TElement> _elements;

    public Grouping(TKey key, IEnumerable<TElement> elements)
    {
        _key = key;
        _elements = elements;
    }

    public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _elements.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public TKey Key
    {
        get { return _key; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not see anything related to `SortBy`, is your topic correct?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to duplicate `GroupBy` semantics exactly, there are several things missing:

- Eager error checking on parameters instead of deferred
- The correct order of the groups (`GroupBy` guarantees that the groups are ordered by the relative order of the group's first element in the source)
- Allowing keys that are `null`

You may be interested in Jon Skeet's [recent blog postings](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/01/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-21-groupby/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you tell me why the order of the groups isn't correct?

Comment: @Oscar Mederos: Dictionary does not guarantee the order that the pairs are returned in, and is usually heavily influenced by the hashing algorithm of the key.

Comment: @Oscar: It's like this - if the keys of the original sequence are `5, 3, 5, 3`, then `GroupBy` produces two groups; the first one is guaranteed to be for key `5` and the second one is guaranteed to be for key `3`. Your implementation returns the groups in an unspecified order.

Comment: As a quick solution, you can handle the ordering issue by storing the keys in the order you receive them in a separate List<TKey> though your final loop will be a little less efficient as you would loop through your List of keys and then yield return from the dictionary using its indexer which isn't as efficient as its enumerator if you're going to use every value.

Comment: Thanks. Understood. For a moment I just forgot that a dictionary is just a HashTable ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (var x in dict)
{
    yield return new Grouping<TKey, TElement>(x.Key, x.Value);
}
```

Could change to:

```
return dict.Select(x => new Grouping<TKey, TElement>(x.Key, x.Value));
```

It's a little thing, but I would make _key and _elements in Grouping readonly.

Comment: Nice. In fact, I implemented `Select` before `GroupBy` too, so it's valid ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One thing that stands out is your Dictionary usage. When checking existence and using a value you should use TryGetValue like so:

```
List<TElement> tmpList;
if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out tmpList))
{
    dict.Add(key, tmpList = new List<TElement>());
}
tmpList.Add(x);
```

Also, in regard to the LINQ change mentioned by mjcopple, there's no need to use Select; it's less efficient and provides no benefit over your yield return in this case. I could understand if it even promoted more readability, but in this case it doesn't and I would stick to your first solution for the sake of efficiency.

No biggie, but since you're just decorating the enumeration of elements, you might as well use it's implementation of the non-generic IEnumerable which will save you a method on the call stack (not much). There's also a chance that the underlying implementation has a more efficient non-generic enumerator than wrapping the generic one (though this is generally uncommon and not the case for List)

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return ((IEnumerable)_elements).GetEnumerator();
}
```

Stephen Cleary makes relevant comments on the completeness of your implementation so I thought I'd just toss out code pointers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will take in count the `TryGetValue`. I use dictionaries lots of time, and I always used `if (dict.Keys.Contains(...))` or `if (dict.ContainsKey(...))` for that purpose. About the `GetEnumerator()`, you're right, but I think that's not a big deal and it's more readable as it is now ;)

Comment: Agreed on the Enumerator front. TryGetValue is one of those things that slipped by a lot of people for a good while, but it's great in premise since it only searches once.